# I get [Object object] when try to render html tag in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
const render = myOpt => (
  <div className="my-class">
    {`${myOpt.isExpired ? <i className='logo-check'></i> : 'not expired'}`}
  </div>
);
```

So, option.isExpired = true but I get [Object object]

Comment: Can you please share details about the component and the context you execute the above code?

Comment: please show us the code

Comment: remove the dollar and it might correctly work or add ticks to your <i>... otherwise it will be counted as an object

Comment: Please share more context. Maybe the full code of the component.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are casting a React/DOM element into a string through the backticks.

Remove dollar and backticks which are useless and put your conditional statement within react component:

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

const RootComponent = (myOpt) => (
  <div className="my-class">
    {myOpt.isExpired ? (<i className='logo-check'>there should be a logo</i>) : 'not expired'}
  </div>
 )
 
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(RootComponent, {isExpired: true}, null), root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

### NOTE:

i added `there should be a logo` in the component on expired as it turned out the problem was not the code in itself but that the logo was not found which made it output an empty `<i>` tag and made it look broken although it worked

Comment: you still get [Object object] ? If so, please add a picture of result.